# Syntax Error in Magento theme - theme.less.php

Tags: php

I just installed a Galatheme titanshop and this error showed up on the storefront. I changed the CHmod permission on the server as the theme author prescribed but yet error persists. Kindly advise.

Syntax Error on line 1

```
in theme.less.php?%40variables_url=%22http%3A%2F%2Fkatangowa.com%2Fskin%2Ffrontend%2Fdefault%2Fgalatitanshop%2Fcss%2Fless%2Ftheme.less%22&%40function_url=%22http%3A%2F%2Fkatangowa.com%2Fskin%2Ffrontend%2Fdefault%2Fgalatitanshop%2Fcss%2Fless%2Ffunctions.less%22&%40screen-large-desktop=1200px&%40screen-desktop=992px&%40screen-tablet=768px&%40desktop=%7E%22%28max-width%3A+767px%29%22&%40tablet=%7E%22only+screen+and+%28min-width%3A+720px%29+and+%28max-width%3A+959px%29%22&%40page_bg_color=%23ffffff&%40page_bg_position=%7E%220+0%22&%40page_bg_repeat=repeat&%40box_shadow=%7E%220+0+5px+%23c4c4c3%22&%40rounded_corner=0&%40general_font=%7E%22normal+12px%2F1.35+Arial%2CHelvetica%2Csans-serif%22&%40h1_font=%7E%22normal+22px%2F1.35+Open+Sans%2CArial%2CHelvetica%2Csans-serif%22&%40h2_font=%7E%22normal+20px%2F1.35+Open+Sans%2CArial%2CHelvetica%2Csans-serif%22&%40h3_font=%7E%22600+18px%2F1.35+Open+Sans%2Chelvetica%2Carial%2Csans-serif%22&%40h4_font=%7E%22600+16px%2F1.35+Open+Sans%2Chelvetica%2Carial%2Csans-serif%22&%40h5_font=%7E%22600+14px%2F1.35+Open+Sans%2Chelvetica%2Carial%2Csans-serif%22&%40h6_font=%7E%22500+12px%2F1.35+Open+Sans%2Chelvetica%2Carial%2Csans-serif%22&%40header_bg_color=%23ffffff&%40header_bg2_color=%230072ff&%40header_bg3_color=%23ffffff&%40header_bg4_color=%231a80ff&%40header_bg5_color=%23005bcc&%40header_bg_position=%7E%220+0%22&%40header_bg_repeat=repeat&%40header_text_color=%23666666&%40header_text2_color=%230072ff&%40header_text3_color=%23ff8401&%40header_text4_color=%23ffffff&%40header_text5_color=%23000000&%40header_line_color=%23d3d3d3&%40topmenu_hover_bg_color=%23ffffff&%40topmenu_text_color=%233b3b3b&%40topmenu_hover_text_color=%23ff8401&%40topmenu_line_color=%23ff8401&%40topmenu_font=%7E%22normal+18px%2F1.35+Open+Sans%2CArial%2CHelvetica%2Csans-serif%22&%40dropmenu_bg_color=%23ffffff&%40dropmenu_text_color=%23666666&%40dropmenu_text2_color=%230072ff&%40dropmenu_line_color=%23d3d3d3&%40dropmenu_font=%7E%22normal+13px%2F1.35+Arial%2CHelvetica%2Csans-serif%22&%40body_bg_color=%23f6f6f6&%40body_bg2_color=%23ffffff&%40body_bg3_color=%23ffffff&%40body_bg4_color=%230072ff&%40body_bg5_color=%23ffffff&%40body_bg6_color=%23f6f6f6&%40body_bg_position=%7E%220+0%22&%40body_bg_repeat=repeat&%40body_text_color=%23ffffff&%40body_text2_color=%23666666&%40body_text3_color=%23000000&%40body_text4_color=%23999999&%40body_text5_color=%230072ff&%40body_text6_color=%23ff8401&%40body_line_color=%23d1d1d1&%40footer_bg_color=%23ffffff&%40footer_bg2_color=%23ffffff&%40footer_bg3_color=%23ffffff&%40footer_bg_position=%7E%220+0%22&%40footer_bg_repeat=repeat&%40footer_text_color=%23666666&%40footer_text2_color=%23000000&%40footer_text3_color=%230072ff&%40footer_text4_color=%23999999&%40footer_text5_color=%23666666&%40footer_line_color=%23d9d9d9&%40footer_line2_color=%23d9d9d9&%40footer_line3_color=%23d9d9d9&%40btn1_bg_color=%230072ff&%40btn1_text_color=%23ffffff&%40btn1_line_color=%230072ff&%40btn1_font=%7E%22600+14px%2F1.35+Open+Sans%2CArial%2CHelvetica%2Csans-serif%22&%40btn2_bg_color=%23000000&%40btn2_text_color=%23ffffff&%40btn2_line_color=%23000000&%40btn2_font=%7E%22600+14px%2F1.35+Open+Sans%2CArial%2CHelvetica%2Csans-serif%22&%40btn3_bg_color=%23ff8401&%40btn3_text_color=%23ffffff&%40btn3_line_color=%23ff8401&%40btn3_font=%7E%22600+14px%2F1.35+Open+Sans%2CArial%2CHelvetica%2Csans-serif%22&%40btn4_bg_color=%2350a914&%40btn4_text_color=%23ffffff&%40btn4_line_color=%2350a914&%40btn4_font=%7E%22600+18px%2F1.35+Open+Sans%2CHelvetica%2Csans-serif%22&%40image_bg_url=%7E%22http%3A%2F%2Fkatangowa.com%2F%22&%40page_bg_image=%7E%22skin%2Ffrontend%2Fdefault%2Fgalatitanshop%2Fimages%2Fstripes%2Fnorwegian_rose.png%22&%40header_bg_image=%7E%22skin%2Ffrontend%2Fdefault%2Fgalatitanshop%2Fimages%2Fstripes%2Fblank.gif%22&%40body_bg_image=%7E%22skin%2Ffrontend%2Fdefault%2Fgalatitanshop%2Fimages%2Fstripes%2Fblank.gif%22&%40footer_bg_image=%7E%22skin%2Ffrontend%2Fdefault%2Fgalatitanshop%2Fimages%2Fstripes%2Fblank.gif%22 on line 1, column 4:

1

            @import \"http://katangowa.com/skin/frontend/default/galatitanshop/css/less/functions.less\";

2

                @import \"http://katangowa.com/skin/frontend/default/galatitanshop/css/less/theme.less\";
```

Comment: well when the first line of theme.less.php indeed starts with ` @import \"http`, that is not valid PHP, on the other hand it is not valid Less code either. Check your PHP settings and find out why the quotes are escaped.